# Page Scroll down and mouse positioning issue with LobsterPot HTML5 PivotViewer

Tags: cursor, html5-canvas, pivotviewer

there is one issue with page scroll down you can,t select any tile i that for this try to re size your browser

and create a vertical scroll and then select any tile you will see the issue. please see this screen shot am facing this issue in html5 version. Thanks any help will be appriciated

Please see the attached screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i got success to get resolved the issue. by getting scroll top and scroll left in jquery to get highlight specific tile in pivotviewer . so now when page resize it don,t disturb its position. :P